# Is this an unbiased estimator for $\theta$?

Tags: unbiased-estimator

Let $\hat \theta_1(X)$ and $ \hat \theta_2(X)$ be two unbiased estimators of $\theta$. Prove that for any $ a \in \Bbb R$, $$\hat \theta_3(X) := a \hat \theta_1(X) +(1-a) \hat \theta_2(X)$$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

How I tried to prove it:

> So by definition :
>
> If the following holds: $$ \Bbb E[u(X_1,...,X_n)] = \theta$$ then the statistic $u(X_1,...,X_n)$ is an unbiased  estimator of the parameter $\theta$.  Otherwise, $u(X_1,...,X_n)$ is a biased estimator of $\theta$.

So,

$\Bbb E[(\hat \theta_3(x)] = \Bbb E[a\hat \theta_1(x)+(1-a) \hat \theta_2(x)] = $

$a\Bbb E[\hat \theta_1(x)] + \Bbb E[\hat \theta_2(x)] - a \Bbb E[\hat \theta_2(x)] 
$

$= a \hat \theta_1(x) + \hat \theta_2(x) - a \hat \theta_2(x)$.

So i'm not completely sure, is this supposed to be an unbiased estimator for $\theta$?

**Edit:** I was mistakenly thinking that the expectation of $\hat \theta_i(x)$ should be equal to  $\hat \theta_i(x)$ (if it's unbiased) and not $\theta$. So after I consider this mistake I arrive to this conclusion:
$a\Bbb E[\hat \theta_1(x)] + \Bbb E[\hat \theta_2(x)] - a \Bbb E[\hat \theta_2(x)] 
=$

$= a  \theta +  \theta - a  \theta = \theta$.

Hence $\Bbb E[\hat \theta_3(x)] = \theta$ and it is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$

Comment: please add `self-study` as a tag.

Comment: The argument is incorrect as it is missing expectations in half of the terms.

Comment: Please be careful to use the notation correctly.  For instance, the assumption that the $\hat\theta_i$ are unbiased means $E[\hat\theta_i]=\theta:$ there are neither subscripts nor hats on the right hand side.

Comment: Now that you have found the answer, please write it up and post it as an answer to this question to help future visitors to this site. It’s OK to answer your own question.